# Haskell attoparsec parser using insane amount of memory

Tags: haskell

I got this function that parses a string with special characters escaped by a backslash.

```hs
parseEscapedString :: Parser String
parseEscapedString =
    char '\''
        *> many'
            ( notChar '\'' >>= \case
                '\\' -> anyChar
                c -> pure c
            )
        <* char '\''
```

I'm using `attoparsec`, specifically `Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8`

While this function works as expected it uses insane amounts of memory when parsing large amounts of strings.

I have a file that's 850Mb in size and contains stuff that I want to parse, part of which are these strings.
But when I try to parse this file the program needs around 10Gb of memory to successfully complete (`-O2`).

When compiled with `-prof` and run with `+RTS -hc` the heap usage statistics show that the main parsing function slightly increases memory usage which is to be expected for allocating the parsed structures, however, the biggest memory usage comes from the function `parseEscapedString` and is absolutely enormous.

Is this a memory leak from `attoparsec` or `bytestring` or did I screw something up?

[image: heap statistics]
(This was saved 40s after running, but when compiled with `-prof` the program is rather slow and runs about 5min before getting killed because of insufficient memory (using around 20GB) which leads to the statistics not being saved but I don't think there's any difference to the first 40 seconds.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with attoparsec, but I'd try replacing the first `anyChar` with `notChar '\''`. Otherwise, it looks like `mempty` would fail too late (?).

Comment: It isn't very clear what you are trying to do. Could you provide an example of a string you want to parse?. Notice the last `char '\''` wont be executed ever, because the inner lambda already consumes it.

Comment: @chi same behaviour with `notChar '\''`

Comment: @Ismor for example a string could look like this: `'abc\'def\.\_ '`, but the parser works just fine, the last `'` does not get consumed by the case statement since it returns `mempty`, otherwise this would try to consume two single ticks and the parser would fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may just be the storage of the `String`s themselves.

Recall that a GHC `String` is a linked list representation.  It turns out that it requires 24 bytes per character "node" (consisting of three 64-bit quads per node: the info pointer for the `:` constructor, a pointer to the `Char`, and a pointer to the next node).  If, say, 50% of your 850MB file consists of strings, parsing it will require `0.50*850*24=10200` megabytes of resident string storage.  This is independent of the details of your parser.  You would see the same issue with a parser like:

```
everything :: Parser String
everything = many' anyChar
```

The simplest fix is to parse into a strict `Text` or `ByteString` representation.  Since you're only handling `Char8` strings, a `ByteString` representation makes sense.  The following Parser ought to work.  You will still need resident storage equal to the total `ByteString` needs of your strings, but it should be 24 times less storage than the plain `String` representation:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

parseEscapedString :: Parser C.ByteString
parseEscapedString = fmap C.pack $
    char '\''
        *> many'
            ( notChar '\'' >>= \case
                '\\' -> anyChar
                c -> pure c
            )
        <* char '\''
```

Comment: Yes, omg that's correct, how could I not see this?